# how to do dynamic BarChart Plotting in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, xcode8, bar-chart

I am trying to create a BarChart in swift3 and it contains,

- x-axis - array of 24 hours and
- y axis - dynamic values of count coming from Firebase for each hour.

I want to know, how do I assign incoming values from Firebase dynamically to respective hours(on x-axis) to y-axis.
Thank you in advance.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCEW.png)

Comment: You can use this libary(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for Anychart and refresh after every one hour.

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Yes, I tried but it doesn't take the dynamic data.It just reflects the previous data.

Comment: Then you should include the code so that we can help you with that

Comment: add code as text, not as a screenshot.. and mention which BarChart library you are using

Comment: @VishalKalola I'm using the same.But when  data is inserted dynamically it doesn't reflects any changes.

Comment: Every Time set new Data into Charts. @IamDeveloper

Answer (score 4):

```
var yVals1 = [Any]()
for i in 0..<AddYourArray.count {
    yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: i, y: AddYourArray[i].value(forKey: "Value")!))
}
var set1: LineChartDataSet? = nil
set1 = LineChartDataSet(values: yVals1, label: "DataSet 1")
chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(_ Index: Double, _ abc: ChartAxisBase?) -> String in
    return AddYourArray[Index].value(forKey: "date") as? String ?? ""
})
var dataSets = [Any]()
dataSets.append(set1)
var data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
chartView.data = data
```